# Safari used 70 GB of RAM

Tags: safari

Safari uses too much memory on my system (rMBP 2013). By 'too much' I mean tens of gigabytes of memory. I experience constant memory pressure which leads to Safari freezes (it's freezing constantly even now while I'm typing this, and I have a single tab opened). It doesn't stop using memory until the entire SSD is full.

- The are no extensions installed (they are disabled in fact).
- I can't tell whether the issue is caused by any particular website; sometimes it happens when I don't have any seemingly "heavy" websites open.

How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does this occur only in your user account or with another account as well? Which extensions do you have installed, do you visit pages with plugins (e.g. Flash)? Does Safari need 70 GB right after starting or only after some time/if you visit specific sites?

Comment: There is a single user account on my system. The are no extensions installed (they are disabled in fact). I do visit Youtube, Google Drive, Gmail, other Google services; as well as many other services (StackOverflow, Basecamp, Jira, etc). I can't tell whether the issue is caused by any particular website; sometimes it happens when I don't have any seemingly "heavy" websites open.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can try...

1. Sometimes applications have memory leaks where the memory bloats over time, if you've been using Safari heavily, or using it for a long time without exiting and rebooting this could be an issue. Quitting Safari and reopening should fix this.
2. Check for extensions, and plugins that Safari uses to see if there are any malicious or unexpected plugins/try removing them temporarily to see if this fixes the issue.

Details of the Plug-Ins folders: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19241?locale=en_GB&viewlocale=en_US

**Best to do a backup before tinkering in the Library folders!**

3. Try creating a new user account and see if Safari has the same issue in this account.

Comment: 1. Not the case; 2. No extensions and plugins except for Adobe Flash; 3. I'll try a clean system install I guess.

Comment: Before you do that, try cleaning out Safari's preferences in your user directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is specific to your regular user account. That would narrow it down to any Safari plug-in or extension unique to the regular User Account. So i would suggest you to focus on extensions first. If you have one or more extensions installed follow these steps.

Open Safari Preferences>Extensions and disable each extension by clicking on the extension, then unchecking the "enable" box. Then, restart Safari.

If performance improves, then return to Safari Preferences and enable one or two extensions. Restart Safari. If CPU activity is normal, then continue down the list following the above sequence until you find what causing this issue.

As with any major OS or application update, it's up to the 3rd party developer to bring their product into compliance with new system requirements.

Comment: I don't have any extensions installed (there are disabled).